# Generating dynamic SAP Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2010 VB.net SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I need to generate a report for a table like shown below

```
REGNO       DATE        YEAR    BATCH   H1  H2  H3  H4  H5  ATT
1138M0322   01-12-2013  3       1       A   P   P   P   P   2
1138M0324   01-12-2013  3       1       A   P   P   P   P   2
1138M0325   01-12-2013  3       1       A   P   P   P   P   2
1138M0329   01-12-2013  3       1       P   P   P   P   P   P
1138M0331   01-12-2013  3       1       P   P   P   P   P   P
```

I need to generate report where the **date is 01-12-2013 and year is 3 and batch is 1**

I added the table to the report. But I need to generate reports dynamically like said above. How can I do this

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parameters. Create 3 parameters, one for date, one for year and one for batch. Then in your selection formula you write "date = {dateParameter} and year {yearParameter} and batch = {batchParameter}. When you run the report it will ask you to enter the parameter values and then the report will show you the data that matches the parameters.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: While adding parameters there are three columns **Value, Description and Parameters.** Can you explain me about these?

Comment: And I may sound dumb, **Where can I add the SELECTION formula?**

Comment: I'm about to leave for a social engagement and will try to answer your further questions in the morning.

Comment: I installed **CRforVS_13_0_6** Sorry I wasn't able to find the version

Comment: Dineshabu, unfortunately I can't connect to my work PC at the moment, but take a look at this link and maybe it'll help answer the questions you have at the moment. http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-string-parameter.htm